# Spark job randomly hangs int the middle of a stage while reading data

Tags: apache-spark

I have a spark job which reads data, transforms it(shuffle involved) and writes data back to disks. Different instances of the same spark job is used for processing separate data in parallel(each has its input\output dir). Some of the jobs, so far, 3 jobs out of 200 roughly, got stuck in the middle of reading stage. By stuck I mean there is no tasks finished after some point, there is no progress in stage, there is no new errors logs of executors in UI, a job can run for half an hour and then it stops and there is no progress. When I rerun the whole set of jobs, everything can be fine or some other jobs can hang again, this time some others(another in/out dir). We use spark 1.6.0(CDH_5.8). We use dynamic allocation and such a job can eat more resources after it already "stuck". Any idea what can be done in such situations?
I start jobs using this properties:

```
--master yarn-cluster 
--driver-memory 8g 
--executor-memory 4g 
--conf spark.yarn.executor.memoryOverhead=1024 
--conf spark.dynamicAllocation.maxExecutors=2200 
--conf spark.yarn.maxAppAttempts=2
--conf spark.dynamicAllocation.enabled=true
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

**UPADATE**

Disabling dynamic allocation seems solved the issue, we are gonna try running our jobs another several days to conclude was it really the reason.

Comment: We're facing the same issue in our Spark Cluster. Did disabling dynamic allocation help?